# pass variables $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, call

I want to pass js variables to an $.ajax function, like:

```
function myCall(elm) {
    var table = $('#realtime').dataTable(); 
    var extension = $(elm).closest("tr").find('td.extension').text();
    var agent = $(elm).closest("tr").find('td.name').text();
    alert(extension);

    $.ajax("/cura/pages/realtime/test.php/",{
        type: "GET",
        data:   {action:'agentpause',pauselocation: extension,queue: 'testq',paused: 'true'}            
    });
}
```

Only extension is a variable, rest hard coded.
Then it doesn't work. If i hard code the value for extension variable, then the $.ajax call is successful. 
What's going wrong with passing extension variable?

Comment: This looks OK. What does alert(extension); tell you? What if you replace this with console.log(extension) - what then appears in the console? Are there any other errors in the console?

Comment: alert(extension) shows the value of the variable as it should be, for example: sip/1600. console.log(extension), then see nothing.

Comment: How exactly do you know that the call was not successful? What **exactly** "does not work"?

Comment: The `/cura/pages/realtime/test.php/` script doesn't execute. When I hard code the extension value in $.ajax call, then the `/cura/pages/realtime/test.php/` script works, when clicking the button.

Comment: It's just text, like: sip/1600. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Can you verify the data sent to your server ? (Google Chrome -> Ctrl+Shift+J -> Network -> the XmlHttpRequest -> Headers)

Comment: That clarifies: successful post is sent like: sip/1600. When extension variable is defined in $.ajax call, then in the url it's sent as: sip%2F1600. Anyway to fix this on js side? Or maybe easier to fix on php script that receives the call?

Comment: @queval_j Thanks! That put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

There was a whitespace added in front of the variable value, in the table. 
Removing the white space in $.ajax function with trim(), like:

```
(extension.trim())
```

Now the $.ajax call is successful.